# How to set image in custom listview in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application in which I have to show ratings depending on the values that I am receiving after parsing the XML response in listview. I have implemented it using the Custom Adapter and showing the images in the getView() method like :

```
String rating = Constants.menuRatingList.get(position);

if (rating.equals("1")) {
  rateImg1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stary);                      
}
```

The problem is when I scroll the down to the last item and again move upwards, it is redrawing the list row.

Someone please suggest me approach to stop the redrawing the list row and set the image value permanently.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the rateImg1 variable?
Maybe you should get it from the view that is passed to the getView() method?
Something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
if (view == null) {
view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
}
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image)).setImageResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
return view;
}
```

Also you can implement getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() and check them in the above method not to redraw the same image if it is already set.

Comment: I am using the imageview by the same method,rateImg1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rateImg1);Can you please let me know how to use getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() by providing me a small snippet...would be a great help..

Comment: Ok. For example you've got 3 images. getViewTypeCount() must return 3 - the count of types you've got and getItemViewType() return an integer from 0 till 2 - the type of the image the view must contain. Then in getView() replace the code which sets the image with this: int type = getItemViewType(); if (type != imageView.getTag()) {switch (getItemViewType()) {case 0: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1); imageView.setTag(0); break; case 1: ... and so on}} Something like this.

Comment: thanks a lot Nixan for your kind suggestions..I've tried your above mentioned approach but I got stucked as I could not understand it properly. Below I mentioning my code which I am using right now..can you please let me know the corrections??

Comment: the site is not allowing me to enter the entire class..can you please give me your email id. I'll forward it to you??